# How to interact with Ant Design calendar from Selenium?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, antd

I have an app using a calendar from [Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/).

The date picker seems to be a read only attribute. I need to interact with this element from Selenium in Python.

To get around it, I tried the following code:

```
self.driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('.ant-calendar-picker-input.ant-input').readOnly = false")
self.driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('.ant-calendar-picker-input.ant-input').value ='12-12-2021'")
self.driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('.ant-calendar-picker-input.ant-input').readOnly = true")
```

With this code the date does not get updated (it does change on the UI, but the date HTML attribute is empty). What am I doing wrong?

Here are screenshots of the HTML code:
[image]
After the date gets updated (manually):
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `HTML` that you've shared, I would `advise` you to use the below code to update the `date picker field`, you do not need to `click` in date picker at all, just run the below **JS** code.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
date_to_fill = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#codigo_fecha_vencimiento input.ant-calendar-picker-input.ant-input")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '15-09-2021')", date_to_fill)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! it worked! Sorry for the basic question, but how did you figure that out? Do you have any resources from where I could learn more about how to effectively interact with html? Thanks again!

Comment: Those are basically Js call, and explicit waits with css selector, https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait and https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the resources! I marked the answer as accepted!